# Grails ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have Foriegn key relation ship between 2 Grails domain class(tables)

```
class ServiceProvider {

    String name
    String address
}

class FieldsDetails implements Serializable {


    Integer serviceProviderId

}
```

I have removed the fields which are not of interest. When I execute any method on **FieldsDetails** domain class, I get the below error

```
ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Unknown column 'this_.service_provider_id' in 'field list'
```

DataSource Entry

```
development {
        dataSource {
            //dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            //url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            url = 'jdbc:mysql://54.169.168.27/zonalde'
            driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
            username = 'root'
            password = ''
            dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        }
    }
```

Please help

Comment: does your table 'field list' does not have a column 'service_provider_id'? this is what the error message states after all.

Comment: There is no table with name field list. it's generic error.

Comment: and yet the error would indicate, that a column is missing.  maybe you could add more informations about the used database (e.g. is it the inmem h2 default or are you trying to map an existing one).

Comment: Whats the value of dbCreate in your DataSource configuration?

Comment: @SandeepPoonia dbCreate is commented. Copied the relevant parts in the question now for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

In your DataSource.groovy `dbCreate` is commented. That means grails is not automatically generating db schemas for you. And you probably have a DB with no tables.

It should have one of the values `create, create-drop, update, validate`. Unless you are not creating schema by yourself or using some migration plugin.

There are 4 values to choose from:

```
create - On startup of your application, this will drop and recreate your schema. This will make sure that you will always have a clean table structure, and all your data is reset on every startup. This is ideal when you are in the early stages of the project and heavily modifying your data model. You will need to spend more time on your Bootstrap though, to create all background data that you need.

create-drop - This will behave exactly like create when starting up your application, with addition that it will drop all your tables when the application is shut down properly or gracefully. I would prefer the create method, because you still have the chance to inspect your database after stopping your application.

update - This will not recreate your schema or any of your tables, but will instead try to synch the database with your current data model. This is done by adding the missing tables or columns to your database. This however is ideal when you are in the middle of development, where it is not practical to put most of your test data in the Bootstrap.

validate - this will not alter your database, but will just compare your data model with the database on start up. And create warnings if necessary. This is ideal when deploying to production environment.
```